# Orientdb live query is giving exception

Tags: orientdb

I am getting below error in executing live query ,

Code to register :

```
List<ODocument> result = db.getRawGraph().query(new OLiveQuery<ODocument>("live select from TEST", listener));
        liveToken = result.get(0).field("token");
```

i followed [live query](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/Live-Query.md#livequery-in-java) document to create the listener

ERROR :

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.live select from TEST
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:72)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:42)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1517)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:72)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery.run(OSQLSynchQuery.java:85)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1319)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:396)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:223)
at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
```

Pom.xml - orient.version - 2.1.7

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
        <version>${orient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
        <version>${orient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>${orient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
        <version>${orient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: i missed the statement mentioned in document to enable live query plugin since i am using 2.1.5 , 

`<handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.livequery.OLiveQueryPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>`

Comment: Hi Linus, I tried importing all libraries of the folder lib
and set 
<handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.livequery.OLiveQueryPlugin"> <parameters> <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/> </parameters> </handler>
in the file orientdb-server-config.xml
and it works

Comment: hi Alessandro , sorry i forgot to mention in my previous comment that after enabling the plugin it works..!  

but i am facing one more issue , when i update data from studio i get callback in my listener , but if i try to access record inside `onLiveResult` function i get error : `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database instance is not set in current thread. Assure to set it with: ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db);`
and even i am not able to open one more instance ,( i get timeout error)

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: Register : 

`MyListener listener = new MyListener();
   ODatabaseDocumentTx db = factory.openDatabase().getRawGraph();
   List<ODocument> result = db.query(new OLiveQuery<ODocument>("live select from sdmproject", listener));
   int liveToken1 = result.get(0).field("token");`


Listener CLass: 

`public class MyListener implements OLiveResultListener {
 public List<ORecordOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ORecordOperation>();
 
 @Override
 public void onLiveResult(int iLiveToken, ORecordOperation iOp)
   throws OException {
  System.out.println("Live token : "+iLiveToken+iOp.record);
 }

}`

Comment: I have tried:
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(path);
ODatabaseDocumentTx db=factory.getTx().getRawGraph();
MyListener listener = new MyListener();
List<ODocument> result = db.query(new OLiveQuery<ODocument>("live select from test", listener));
int liveToken1 = result.get(0).field("token");
and it works

Comment: Getting token and registering a listener is working ,. But when I do any update on the class from studio and try to access the record in listener it gives the error .,    have you tried this scenario ?